# How to scrape a Table with Selenium and Python 3.6 on windows 10

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.6

I am trying my hard to scrape data from a website and write data to CSV file.
then after writing to file change page to continue the process till last page.
i am getting data from first row only. I am doing something wrong .
Kindly correct me.

```
import re
import os
import csv
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver =webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.census2011.co.in/district.php')
driver.maximize_window()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='DataTables_Table_0_length']/label/div/select") )
select.select_by_visible_text("100")

for i in range(1,101,1) :
    sNo = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[1]")
    district = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[2]/a")
    districtName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[2]").text
    state= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[3]").text
    population= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[4]").text
    growth= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[5]").text
    sexRatio= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr['+str(i)+']/td[6]").text
    districtLink = district.get_attribute("href")
    print(districtName,state,population,growth,sexRatio,districtLink)


with open(r"D:\python36_files\censusDistrictData.csv",'a',newline = "\n", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ["DistrictName", "State", "Population",  "Growth","SexRatio","DistrictLink"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ["DistrictName", "State", "Population",  "Growth","SexRatio", "DistrictLink"],restval='none',delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerow({'DistrictName': districtName, 'State': state, 'Population':population,  'Growth':growth, 'SexRatio':sexRatio, 'DistrictLink': districtLink})

print ("OK")
driver.quit()
```

and another question:
I have tried by scraping CSS Selector but not able to put a separator after col.

```
import re
import os
import csv
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver =webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.census2011.co.in/district.php')
driver.maximize_window()

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='DataTables_Table_0_length']/label/div/select") )
select.select_by_visible_text("100")
districtTable = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#DataTables_Table_0")
for row in districtTable:
    print(row.text)
with open(r"D:\python36_files\censusDistrictData1.csv",'a',newline = "\n", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ["Row"],restval='none',delimiter = ';')
    writer.writerow({"Row":row.text}) #pl.let me know how to insert ; after a data to a csvfile


print ("OK")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: both questions are combined because I have seen answers to scrape with CSS Selector which create this problem that cannot be separated with some separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've just left out the indent under the `for` loop

```
for i in range(1,101):
    trXpath = "//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]"
    sNo = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[1]")
    districtLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[2]/a").get_attribute("href")
    districtName = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[2]").text
    state= driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[3]").text
    population= driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[4]").text
    growth= driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[5]").text
    sexRatio= driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[6]").text
    print(districtName, state, population, growth, sexRatio, districtLink)
```

I've simplified the code a little to make it easier to read and maintain.

Comment: But it is not solving the problem. This code keeps on giving output of first row irrespective of changing starting step of Range or changing 'str' part.

Comment: Print `trXpath` and make sure it's incrementing. The XPath should work as long as the index is increasing each loop. I don't do python so I can't test it myself.

Comment: @ JeffC, still the same issue

Comment: What is printed for the `trXpath`?

Comment: //table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[' + str(i) + ']

Comment: OK. I see what is going on.. you were using single quotes (') instead of double quotes (") around `str(i)` which wasn't closing the string. I updated my answer... try it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139668/discussion-between-dd-sharma-and-jeffc).

Answer (score 0):

This question was solved by me but not the right way in Python, Kindly guide me in details.

```
import re
import os
import csv
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from  selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('http://www.census2011.co.in/district.php')
driver.maximize_window()
select =     Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='DataTables_Table_0_length']/label/div/select") )
select.select_by_visible_text("100")
i = 0
for i in range(0, 100):
    i += 1    
    baseXpath = "//table[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr["
    row = str(i)
    trXpath = baseXpath + row + ']'
    sNo = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[1]")
    districtLink = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[2]/a").get_attribute("href")
    districtName = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[2]").text
    state = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[3]").text
    population = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[4]").text
    growth = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[5]").text
    sexRatio = driver.find_element_by_xpath(trXpath + "/td[6]").text
    print(districtName,';', state,';', population,';', growth,';', sexRatio)
    with open(r"D:\python36_files\censusDistrictData.csv",'a',newline = "\n", encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ["DistrictName", "State", "Population",  "Growth","SexRatio","DistrictLink"]
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames = ["DistrictName", "State", "Population",  "Growth","SexRatio", "DistrictLink"],restval='none',delimiter = ';')
        writer.writerow({'DistrictName': districtName, 'State': state, 'Population':population,  'Growth':growth, 'SexRatio':sexRatio, 'DistrictLink': districtLink})

print ("OK")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: No dear, I have made mistake in this code and I have put it for correcting and I have given your answer right which has guided me to make correct code.